# How create a scrum dashboard with all my jira issues

Tags: jira, scrumboard

we have a JIRA dashboard with the following columns

- To Do
- In Progress
- In Review
- Done

When I click on a user I would like the scrum dashboard to display only the issues that are on the users plate, i.e

- All the issues that the user has To Do
- All the issues that the user has In Progress (stuff they are doing)
- All the issues that the user has In Review (stuff they are reviewing)
- All the issues that the user has Done (issues that the have been
  completed and the user was involved with, i.e. they did the work,
  they reviewed the work)

How can I create/amend the "In Review" and "Done" columns on the scrum board to show tickets that are on the user's plate.
I don't want to show stuff the user has moved into "In Review" or "Done".

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the Group By Button you can group by assignee. Every task which is assigned to say Eric is then grouped in one section and every task assigned to tom is grouped in another section. (See image at the bottom)

I think you could also search for the user in the searchbox.

Also you can create filter.

[image: Jira Screenshot]

[Edit] Click on the usericon next to the searchbox and tasks are filtered per assigned user.

Comment: Thanks but would Group By Assignee also show what "Eric" still has to go and review? I am not interested in what Eric has moved into Review. John may have moved a task into Review and Eric needs to go review it. How would Eric know that he has to review something John has resolved?

Comment: When John is done with his job, he assigns the task to Eric, so that Eric is assignee.

Comment: The assigne field shows who has the task currently. The reporter field shows who created the task.